# Onclick Event fires multiple times

Tags: asp.net, gridview, detailsview

I have a gridview. In this gridview I'm having a detailsView in a templateField.

In a detailsView there's an asp button in detailsview's templateField.

I'm having a both customValidator and requiredFieldValidator in a validationGroup of a button and textbox.

Now, I'm really confused with an onClick event, very strange. When I click the button the ButtonClicked event is firing as many times as how many items present in a gridview. So the customvalidator tends to check all of the Buttons, and returns false eventually.

[image]

Comment: These Detailsviews are kinda dynamically created, have the same IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after several days, I've found a work-around.

I've come to send needed parameters via code-behind on a DetailsView_OnDataBound(). The point is to set ValidationGroups from codebehinds. (So it should be empty in the layout!)

Generally, Like this:

```
if(currentRequestID== GridView1.SelectedValue){
(Button) Button1 = DetailsView1.FindControl("Button1");

Button1.ValidationGroup = "ValGroup";

CustomFieldValidator cfv = DetailsView1.FindControl("Button1");
cfv.ValidationGroup = "ValGroup";
//...Other validators and/or buttons
}
```